# subsetting dataframe and storing in reactiveValues() seems inconsistant

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny-server, shiny

Thats how I create my first `reactiveValues()`

```
myDataSet <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
```

I have an `actionButton`. When that is clicked this line is executed:

```
    observeEvent(input$go, {
            myDataSet$data <- go-df
    })
```

`go-df` is a dataframe with a few NA`s spread in the rows (but not many)!

I wait for further input from the `ui.R` for subsetting. I store the subsetted results again in `reactiveValues`.

```
    dataSetAbsolute <- reactiveValues(test1= NULL, test2= NULL)


    observe({
            dataSetAbsolute$test1<- subset.data.frame(x = myDataSet$data,
                                                          subset = myDataSet$data$columnx %in% input$chosenbyuser
                                                          %>% na.omit(.))
    })
```

That *seems*  to work right. To check I do `str(dataSetAbsolute $test1)` to see whats in there and what I get is rather confusing.

> 'data.frame': 0 obs. of  22 variables:

It lists everything and everything is empty exept for three columns. **Then**, this is followed by

> 'data.frame': 9 obs. of  22 variables:

There, everything is filled how it is supposed to be.

How can I understand that?!
Why are there two dataframes behind `dataSetAbsolute$test1`?
Do I missunderstand how `reactiveValues()` work and what they are there for?!

Comment: Looking at the bits of code you've given is hard to come up with a conclusion. It would be easier to point out the problem if you provided a reproduceble example (the problem might be on subset.data.frame).

Comment: @user5029763 I think I narrowed it down. Posted a new question (with repr. example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649025/on-assignment-of-reactivevalues-empty-dataframe-created