# on assignment of reactiveValues() empty dataframe created

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

Reproducable example:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {

    myDf <- reactiveValues(myData = NULL)

    problematicDf <- reactiveValues(test = NULL)

    observeEvent(input$myButton, {
            myDf$myData <- df
    })


    observe({
            output$myTestUi <- renderUI({
                    selectInput(inputId = 'mySelection', 
                                label = 'Selection', 
                                choices = levels(myDf$myData$z),
                                multiple = T,
                                selected = c(levels(myDf$myData$z)[1])
                    )
            })
    })


    observe({
            problematicDf$test <- subset(myDf$myData, ((myDf$myData$z %in% input$mySelection)))
    })


    observe({
            str(problematicDf$test)
    })

    observe({
            as.matrix(x = problematicDf$test)
    })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI( bootstrapPage( 

    h3("Push the button"),
    actionButton(inputId = "myButton",
                 label = "clickMe"),

    h4("Split Merkmal"),
    uiOutput("myTestUi")

))
```

**global.R**

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1, z = letters[1:10])
df$z <- as.factor(df$z)
```

This gives me:

```
NULL
[1] "NULL"
NULL
Warning: Unhandled error in observer: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
observe({
    as.matrix(x = problematicDf$test)
})
```

Only looking at the output of

```
observe({
  str(problematicDf$test)
  print(class(problematicDf$test))
  print(problematicDf$test$z)
})
```

after clicking on the `action Button`, without the `as.matrix`, I get:

```
NULL
[1] "NULL"
NULL
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int 
 $ y: int 
 $ z: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 
[1] "data.frame"
factor(0)
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: int 1
 $ y: int 10
 $ z: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1
[1] "data.frame"
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e f g h i j
```

That is problematic. As you can see it creates first a `df` which is sort of empty, with placeholders, of `class = NULL`. And then, it fills this. However, it seems that other `reactive functions`, waiting for the `problematicDf$test` to be created kick in *as soon* as the empty `df` is created (with `class = NULL`). They do not update afterwards anymore. They only update when another selection is made. 
This causes (in my case) the program to crash since I need to keep on working and subsetting etc. with the so created `data.frame`.

How to handle this?!
I could include an `if else` and check for `class = NULL`. But it seems to me that this is an unelegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for you to initialize `myDf` as `NULL`? If not, you could easily solve your problem assigning `df` at it's initialization. If you do so, your code won't need the button either.

And you shouldn't declare your `renderUI` inside `observe`. Whenever you chance the selected item, the `observe` is activated and it will set your selectInput to it's initial state (with only item 'a' selected).

**Edit 1**

# server.R

```
shinyServer( function(input, output, session) {
   # initialize myDf$myData with df and problematicDf as NULL
   myDf <- reactiveValues(myData = df)
   problematicDf <- reactiveValues(test = NULL)

   # you don't have to observe here. once the selectInput 
   # has been created, you can (un)select how many choices you want
   output$myTestUi <- renderUI({
       selectInput(inputId = 'myTestUi', 
                   label = 'Selection', 
                   choices = levels(myDf$myData$z),
                   multiple = T,
                   # this line determines that ONLY the first item on 
                   # c(levels(myDf$myData$z)[1] is selected on the selectInput initialization!
                   selected = c(levels(myDf$myData$z)[1])
       )
   })

   observe({
       problematicDf$test <- subset(myDf$myData, 
                             (myDf$myData$z %in% input$myTestUi))
   })

   observeEvent(input$myButton, {
       # the code in here will only run when the button is pushed!
       print("you should only put things here that you want to be flushed on the button being clicked!")
   })

})
```

**Edit 2**

So do initialize `myDf$myData` as `NULL` and assign df inside the `observeEvent`.

The `renderUI` will begin as a `selectInput` without any choices, but as soon as the button is pushed, choices will be assigned to it.

You mention some `reactive` functions that crash when the data is still `NULL`. There are lots of ways to deal with that. One way is to just use a `if(is.null(myDf$myData)) return(NULL)` as you mentioned. Might not be the most elegant way but usually works just fine. Other ways may include `isolate` or an `observeEvent` (it doesn't react to NULL inputs by default). It depends on how your app work as a whole.

But it seems you haven't fully understood how reactivity and other shiny elements work. Try reading the rstudio articles, specially the 'reactive programming' part (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/).

Comment: I do not initalize it as `NULL`, the framwork does! Thats what I want to point out. It initializes the it as `NULL`. And yes, I need the button! 

I can select several items the way I wrote it, even wrapped in the `observe`, `renderUI` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. I'll edit my answer with a code following my suggestion.

Comment: I have a second actionBtton. Depending on which actionButton I click, a different dataFrame gets assigned to `myDf`. So yes, there is a reason.

Comment: that error occus even if I do not initialize `myDF$myData as NULL`, or `problematicDf as NULL`. Try to run something like `observe({as.matrix(x = problematicDf$test)})`. That crashes. For my understanding, it should not crash! http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html) "When you read a value from it, the calling reactive expression takes a reactive dependency on that value, and when you write to it, it notifies any reactive functions that depend on that value".

Comment: Notifying with NULL, causing other functions which need other input than NULL to work (and other input is given as you can see from my code `selected = c(levels(myDf$myData$z)[1]) `!) to crash, seems like a rather unuseful function here.

Comment: Using the code I wrote and the modifications I mentioned in 'edit 2', I can't reproduce the error on `selected = c(levels(myDf$myData$z)[1])`.

Comment: And about `observe({as.matrix(x = problematicDf$test)})`, the reason it's crashing is because the `as.matrix` function does not accept `NULL` as data. The `reactiveValues` function is not the core problem. It's purpose is to react to changes, not evaluate them .

Comment: Yes, thats right. But what I do not understand is why is `reactiveValues()` assigning `NULL`?! Is there a way around that?